# How can I create the PowerShell variables for working with the static members?

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-hosting

PowerShell 4.0

In my application the `Application` class has the set of important properties, methods, and events. I want to work with that members through the `app` PowerShell variable (it would be like the alias of the class). But the `Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable` expects the instance of the class in the second parameter:

```
using app = CompanyName.AppName.Application;
...
using (Runspace rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace()) {
    rs.ThreadOptions = PSThreadOptions.UseCurrentThread;
    rs.Open();

    // TODO: The problem is here (app is not the instance of 
    //the Application class
    rs.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("app", app); 

    rs.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("docs", app.DocumentManager);

    using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create()) {
        ps.Runspace = rs;

        ps.AddScript("$docs.Count");
        ps.Invoke();
    }
    rs.Close();
}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `typeof` operator in C# to get `System.Type` instance, which represent specified type. In PowerShell you can use static member operator `::` to access to static members of some type.

```
using app = CompanyName.AppName.Application;
...
using (Runspace rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace()) {
    rs.ThreadOptions = PSThreadOptions.UseCurrentThread;
    rs.Open();

    rs.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("app", typeof(app)); 

    using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create()) {
        ps.Runspace = rs;

        ps.AddScript("$app::DocumentManager");
        ps.Invoke();
    }
    rs.Close();
}
```